# Python complex number __add__ not working

Tags: python-3.x

I need to make this for python class.
So this is the code for overlaping operator for add :

```
class complex_number :
    def __init__(self, real,imaginary=0.0) :
        self.real = real
        self.imaginery = imaginary
    def __add__ (self, other):
        return complex_number(self.real + other.real,self.imaginery + other.imaginery)
x = complex(2,10j)
y = complex(3,5j)
z = x + y
```

My problem is that I am getting a wrong result.
Im getting (-10,0j)
Correct result is (5,15j)
Some other info. I found work of other people online and Im still getting the wrong result.
addition of complex numbers goes like this : (a + bi) + (c + di) = (a +c)+(b+d)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you assign to `x` and `y` standart `complex` class, not your `complex_number`.

also writing `j` is error. What is this `j`?

this works fine:

```
class complex_number :
    def __init__(self, real, imaginary=0.0):
        self.real = real
        self.imaginary = imaginary
    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.real} + {self.imaginary}*i';
    def __add__(self, other):
        return complex_number(self.real + other.real, self.imaginary + other.imaginary)
x = complex_number(2,10)
y = complex_number(3,5)
z = x + y

print(z) // output: 5 + 15*i
```

Comment: Just realized, that `__str__` does not work properly on negative numbers in imaginary part

Comment: **Update** `signStr = '+' if self.imaginary >= 0 else ''
        return f'{self.real}{signStr}{self.imaginary}*i';` this works properly

Comment: Thank you mate, I think I understand, and j is what I was getting in output not i.

Answer (score -2):

I found the problem by accident.

```
x = complex(2,10)
y = complex(3, 5)
```

j is not supposed to be writen.

Comment: It's still invalid. complex() is probably not the class you intended to use. You (probably accidentally) used Python's [complex](https://python-reference.readthedocs.io/en/latest/docs/complex/) function.

Comment: @Maaz Yeah you are right mate. Still new at python.